# What is Booksleave IKeyCommands.Find equivalent in StackExchange.Redis

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

Earlier our source was using Booksleave library to connect to Redis, and now we are migrating the source to use StackExchange.Redis library. In the existing source we have used the Find command as below

var t = conn.Keys.Find(database, keyPattern);

What is the equivalent function for Find in StackExchange.Redis library ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var server = conn.GetServer(someServer);

server.Keys(pattern: "*foo*");
```

Where *foo* is your keypattern.

https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/KeysScan.md

Comment: Thanks Karthikeyan, this is what I was looking for. I am using this overload  Keys(int database, RedisValue pattern, int pageSize, CommandFlags flags). The parameter pageSize here is referring to the number of keys returned in a SCAN iteration right? Do you have any idea?

Comment: In naive redis keys is a blocking command instead you can use scan command multiple times with the cursor returned so that it is not blocking. In this library, keys will internally implement the scan to avoid blockages. And yes here pageSize refers to number of keys returned during each iteration. If you give this too much, you may feel some blockages. If you give it very low the time to pass this command will be slow. By trying out with different ranges, you need to derive an optimal number that suits your system.